# Maximum of a function

Tags: calculus

Let $h(y):=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2-1})-y^2-y\sqrt{y^2-1},\ y\geq 1$. I need to prove that this function has a global maximum on the interval $(1,\infty)$ at some point $y^*$ and that $h(y^*)<-0.95$.

A simpler function of interest is $g(y):=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2-1})-y^2,\ y\geq 1,$ with the same goal.

The exact point of maximum is not needed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that $h(y)$ has a global maximum on $(1,\infty)$...at least, not when I look at a graph of $h(y)$.

Comment: This is odd, I must have made a mistake about $h$, I'll check at work tomorrow. How about $g$ then?

Comment: I did make a mistake when plotting $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** In accordance with your comment, I will prove that there exists a maximum of $g$:
$$g(y)=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2-1})-y^2\\
\implies g^{'}(y)=\dfrac{1}{y+\sqrt{y^2-1}}\left(1+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\right)-2y\\
\implies g^{'}(y)=0\text{ at the solution of }2y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\\
\implies 4y^2=\dfrac{1}{{y^2-1}}$$
The solution in $(1,\infty)$ is
$$y=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}$$